# How to return Return Promise from Array.reduce

Tags: javascript, types, promise

I am iterating over an array of objects using `Array.reduce` and trying to return promise from there. I making some modifications inside the reduce method and after the promise resolved `reviewCards['departments']` key within the object has the modified data but `reviewCards['genders']` is empty. I think all the promises are not resolving properly.

**How I can return the final Object as Promise?**

```
public getCompanyReviewCards(
   reviewGroups: ICompanyReviewGroups,
   reviews: CompanyReview[],
): Promise<[key: string]: ICompanyReviewCard> {
  
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
      const reviewCards = Object.keys(reviewGroups).reduce(
         async (reviewCards: ICompanyReviewCards, groupKey: string) => {

            const group = reviewGroups[groupKey];
            reviewCards['genders'] = reviewCards['genders'] || [];
            reviewCards['departments'] = reviewCards['departments'] || [];

            //Department wise cards
            //This block is excuting properyly
            if (groupKey === '_departmentGroup') {
                 const departmentsCards = await this.getCardsByDepartments(group);
                 reviewCards['departments'] = departmentsCards;
            }

            //Gender wise cards
            //This block is not excuting properyly
            if (groupKey === '_genderGroup') {
                 const gendersCards = await this.getCardsByGender(group);
                 reviewCards['genders'] = gendersCards;
            }

            return reviewCards;

         },Object.create(null),
      );

   resolve(reviewCards);

   })
}
```

Comment: Some libraries are good at it. For example, operator [reduce](https://vitaly-t.github.io/iter-ops/functions/reduce.html) in [iter-ops](https://github.com/vitaly-t/iter-ops) library is fully promise-aware, so you won't need any work-around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`reduce` isn't promise aware and won't handle your promises automatically, so you have to do it yourself. Keep in mind that the first argument to the callback is the value returned from the previous iteration which will be a promise.

```js
const main = async() => {
  const generateNumber = () => {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(Math.random()), 1000));
  };

  const data = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
  const promiseReducedData = data.reduce(async(previousValuePromise, currentValue, index) => {
    const resolvedPreviousValue = await previousValuePromise;
    console.log(`Working on index ${index}`);
    const newValue = {
      ...resolvedPreviousValue,
      [currentValue]: await generateNumber()
    };
    return newValue;
  }, {});
  const reducedData = await promiseReducedData;
  console.log(reducedData);
};

main();
```

Comment: This: `const main = async() => {` and this: `data.reduce(async(previousValuePromise, currentValue, index) => {` caused a moment of confusion. Obviously `async` is not the name of a function but a function modifier. Both are the same as: `const main = async function () {` and: `data.reduce(async function (previousValuePromise, currentValue, index) {`—which are modified anonymous functions. Just not immediately obvious without the (optional) space after `async`, in conjunction with an arrow function.

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles — You might want to take that up with Stackoverflow: It's their code formatting tool that removed the whitespace there :)

Comment: Oh, did you click "Tidy"? I'm annoyed with it sometimes. I have to go back and "untidy" some things. :)